# Hector_Slam mapping Hokuyo

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hokuyo, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to create something similar to this http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=F8pdObV_df4, but i'm not able to create constant good maps.

I'm using hector slam with the hokuyo URG-04LX and an imu for roll/pitch.(so no odometry)
Some (indoor) maps are perfect, but if i try it again the map sometimes drifts and the position in rviz becomes weird.

So my question is: Hector_slam creates its own odometry right? Or do i have to add odometry for proper map results? Or is my laser scanner to weak for hector, so that i need something like hokuyo UTM-30LX?

Thx for your response

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42725/hector_slam-mapping-hokuyo/) by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well Hector is able to work without any odometry support. In such a case Hector uses the laser data only to calc. its location in respect to the map. As long as the laser data are meaning full hector will work well in this mode, i.e. the range, noise, updated rate and vehicle speed stay within some bounds. For example, the hokuyo URG-04LX has a range of 4-7m (if i remember correctly) which means your environment should not have spots larger the 4-7m free space. As rule of the thump you can say that at least 50% of the beams should stay within half of the max range. Therefore your outdoor conditions are easily violating this rule of the thump.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on 2012-08-31**:
Hello thx for your response. So basically i have to avoid spots with over 4-7 meter free space. That would explain the broken maps. Are there any tricks to work around? Or other stacks like hector_slam which could work? Because 4-7 meter is even indoor not that much.

**Comment by [bredzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25340/bredzhang/) on 2015-12-17**:
hector slam can handle slam without any odom param, I can understand  when the robot do the linear move, but  think about this situation, if the robot just do rotation in the same place,  the hector slam can know the rotation accurate? and if it is a round spheric environment, I don't think hector c

**Comment by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on 2016-04-08**:
Depends on your hardware and the enviroment, but yes it can also handle rotations. If you have a short range laser scanner or an enivorement without many charactaristica you are running into problems.